# knpuniversity oauth2client expected state is null often

Tags: facebook, symfony, oauth-2.0

vendor/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle/src/Client/OAuth2Client.php:

[image]

When I logout user and try to login with facebook again, often I get this exception - InvalidStateException. "User see Invalid state parameter passed in callback URL." Thats because there is no data in session. But why that can happen?

Using this bundle:

https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

This is called from my facebook authenticator class:

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        // this method is only called if supports() returns true

        return $this->fetchAccessToken($this->getFacebookClient());
    }
```

Also noticed if I try again to login with facebook after this exception, then it logs in succesfully. But later noticed this is also not always the case.

I am thinking there is soemthing to do with race condition somewhere, because when I use xdebug and code stops at breakpoinst, it often workse ok.

Comment: The `state` value is used for CSRF protection, and the value passed via URL to Facebook and back, must match what is stored in the session afterwards. Here, the value from the session appears to be null for some reason. The state value usually gets created and stored into the session, when the login dialog URL is created, so maybe go investigate in that area, what might be going wrong.

Comment: State value is set in vendor/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle/src/Client/OAuth2Client.php
redirect method. I added logging instantly after saving to session - get the value and it exists. Somewhere else it is cleared. But how to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was chrome sending 2 requests because of prefetching.

https://www.keycdn.com/support/prefetching

When I enter url in address bar (for testing I had not made facebook button yet) chrome instantly loads it. Then I press enter and it loads it again. And things start happing what is unexpected when there are 2 requests to login with facebook.

Tested on firefox, there is no such problem. When I have made link to login to facebook and so I dont have to type in address bar, it also does not make prefetch and problem is gone on chrome also.